# Получить реальный размер формы

Tags: c#, winforms

Хочу получить размеры формы когда она полностью развёрнута.

Вешаю на событие `Form1_Resize` что бы отлавливать размеры.

```
string z = this.Size.ToString();
label1.Text = z;
```

На компьютере показывает 1936 x 1056

- Реальное разрешение экрана = 1920 x 1080

А на ноуте показывает 1374 x 748

- Реальное разрешение экрана = 1366 x 748

**Почему врёт про ширину ?**

Comment: Все дело в так называемой "pixel density". Эта проблема решена в WPF & UWP приложениях. В WinForms вы будете с этим кувыркаться, писать костыли, но ничего путного из этого не выйдет.

Answer (score 2):

`Size` - размеры формы с границами.

`ClientSize` - размер контрола без границы.

Также смотрите свойства `DisplayRectangle` и `ClientRectangle`.